# How to display a section of html based on jQuery form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, show-hide

Hello everyone i am working on a form validation using jQuery ,i am done with form validation, now i want to display section of the html content based on the validation . i.e in my code there are 2 forms`content1` and `content2` , i have given a submit button at the end of each form , now i need to display the 2nd form i.e `content2`only if the 1st form `content1` is completely validated , how can i do that . Thank you very much :)

This is my code 
http://codepen.io/inoxe/pen/QNGVEZ?editors=1010

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>BootstrapValidator</title>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body>



    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="page-header">
                    <h1>Validate </h1>
                </div>
            <!-- form: -->

          <section  id="content1">
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" >

                    <form id="defaultForm1" method="post" class="form-horizontal" >
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>1st Content</legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Username</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Country</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <select class="form-control" name="country">
                                        <option value="">-- Select a country --</option>
                                        <option value="fr">France</option>
                                        <option value="de">Germany</option>
                                        <option value="it">Italy</option>
                                        <option value="jp">Japan</option>
                                        <option value="ru">Russia</option>
                                        <option value="gb">United Kingdom</option>
                                        <option value="us">United State</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-5 col-lg-offset-3">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="acceptTerms" /> Accept the terms and policies
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">

                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value ="a1" >Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </section>


                <section id="content2">         
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2"  >
                        <form id="defaultForm2" method="post"  class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>2nd content</legend>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email address</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Website</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="website" placeholder="http://" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">US Phone number</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumberUS" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">UK Phone number</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phoneNumberUK" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Hex, RGB, HSL, Keyword color</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="color" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">All colors</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="colorAll" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">US zip code</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="zipCode" />
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Password</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Retype password</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-5">
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="confirmPassword" />
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Ages</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ages" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-lg-9 col-lg-offset-3">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value ="a2">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </section>
            <!-- :form -->
        </div>
    </div>




<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#defaultForm1').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },

        fields: {

            username: {
                message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },

            country: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The country is required and can\'t be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            acceptTerms: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'You have to accept the terms and policies'
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });





         $('#defaultForm2').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },

        fields: {   


            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid email address'
                    }
                }
            },
            website: {
                validators: {
                    uri: {
                        allowLocal: true,
                        message: 'The input is not a valid URL'
                    }
                }
            },
            phoneNumberUS: {
                validators: {
                    phone: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid US phone number'
                    }
                }
            },
            phoneNumberUK: {
                validators: {
                    phone: {
                        message: 'The input is not a valid UK phone number',
                        country: 'GB'
                    }
                }
            },
            color: {
                validators: {
                    color: {
                        type: ['hex', 'rgb', 'hsl', 'keyword'],
                        message: 'Must be a valid %s color'
                    }
                }
            },
            colorAll: {
                validators: {
                    color: { }
                }
            },
            zipCode: {
                validators: {
                    zipCode: {
                        country: 'US',
                        message: 'The input is not a valid US zip code'
                    }
                }
            },
            password: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The password is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'confirmPassword',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
            confirmPassword: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The confirm password is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    identical: {
                        field: 'password',
                        message: 'The password and its confirm are not the same'
                    }
                }
            },
            ages: {
                validators: {
                    lessThan: {
                        value: 100,
                        inclusive: true,
                        message: 'The ages has to be less than 100'
                    },
                    greaterThan: {
                        value: 10,
                        inclusive: false,
                        message: 'The ages has to be greater than or equals to 10'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>





</body>
</html>
```

I also tried using jQuery hide and show but it dint worked , and the code which i used was

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){


        $("#content1").show();
        $("#content2").hide();

    $("button").click(function() {
      if ( this.value == 'a1')      
      {
        $("#content1").hide();
        $("#content2").show();
      }
      else  if ( this.value == 'a2')
      {
        $("#content2").hide();
        $("#content1").show();      
      }
 });
});
</script>
```

Please help me out to solve this problem , thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the onSuccess method:

```
$('#defaultForm2').hide();
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#defaultForm1').bootstrapValidator({
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },

        fields: {

            username: {
                message: 'The username is not valid',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The username is required and can\'t be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 6,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The username must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+$/,
                        message: 'The username can only consist of alphabetical, number, dot and underscore'
                    }
                }
            },

            country: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The country is required and can\'t be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            acceptTerms: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'You have to accept the terms and policies'
                    }
                }
            }

        },
            onSuccess: function(e, data) {
                e.preventDefault();
            $('#defaultForm2').show();
            $('#defaultForm1').hide();//hide the first

            }
    });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGZVxg?editors=1010

Note: you will need ajax to submit the first form so the page doesn't refrersh or port the date to the second form submit

Comment: thank u somuch madalin ivascu :)
i also want to hide the 1st form when the second form appears , how can i do that .

Comment: add  `$('#defaultForm1').hide();` after the show of the first in the onsuccess

Answer (score 0):

Use style attribute display:block or display:none instead of hide and how and use html class attribute for initial declaration.  $('selector goes here').css("display",'block');

Comment: thank u shiva , i am new to this coding field so could be more specific and can u please show it in code it would be very helpful for me .

Comment: hello rayon i dont know , i think there is some mistake in my code itself , i am not able to recognize it . can u please help me out .